# How to upload single file on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I uploaded an php laravel application on elastic beanstalk. When I need to update a single file i need to zip the complete application and upload the new version.

Is there any option to upload only the single file in elastic beanstalk?

Comment: No really, unless you want to manually do the changes. Normally you just upload your deployment package again. That's how it works.

Comment: its usually not good practice to update single files.. but you always can do things that are prone to error or dangerous.. If you have access / permission write a cron script that looks for those single file edits in your source control and updates the php source running on the instance. Ugly but that would work if you really had to do it..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In this scenario which aws service is better